WPF用に作った自作のコレクションで、Countの変更を取れる実装と取れない実装で違いが出る原因を知りたい
質問
WPF用にINotifyPropertyChangedを実装した自作のコレクションを作成したのですが、XAMLでCountプロパティをバインディングしても、変更が反映されませんでした。
ObservableCollectionのソースコードを参考にして変更が反映されるよう修正することはできたのですが、なぜこれで上手く動くのかがわかりませんでした。
上手く動く場合と動かない場合で違いが出る原因を知りたいです。
どちらでもINotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChangedが発火できているところまでは確認しています。
再現手順
[Add]ボタンをクリックすると、CollectionAのカウントには変化がありませんが、CollectionBのカウントには変化があります。
ソースコード
Countの変更が反映されないコレクション(CollectionA)
internal class MyCollectionA<T> : IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private readonly ObservableCollection<T> collection = [];

  public MyCollectionA()
  { 
  }

  public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged
  {
    add => collection.CollectionChanged += value;
    remove => collection.CollectionChanged -= value;
  }

  event PropertyChangedEventHandler? INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
  {
    add => ((INotifyPropertyChanged)collection).PropertyChanged += value;
    remove => ((INotifyPropertyChanged)collection).PropertyChanged -= value;
  }

  public T this[int index] { get => collection[index]; set => collection[index] = value; }
  public int Count => collection.Count;
  public bool IsReadOnly => false;
  public bool Contains(T item) => collection.Contains(item);
  public int IndexOf(T item) => collection.IndexOf(item);
  public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) => collection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
  public void Add(T item) => collection.Add(item);
  public void Insert(int index, T item) => collection.Insert(index, item);
  public bool Remove(T item) => collection.Remove(item);
  public void RemoveAt(int index) => collection.RemoveAt(index);
  public void Clear() => collection.Clear();
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => collection.GetEnumerator();
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => collection.GetEnumerator();
}

Countの変更が反映されるコレクション(CollectionB)
internal class MyCollectionB<T> : IList<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private readonly ObservableCollection<T> collection = [];

  public MyCollectionB()
  {
    // protectedのPropertyChangedを経由するようにした点が変更点です。
    ((INotifyPropertyChanged)collection).PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
  }

  public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged
  {
    add => collection.CollectionChanged += value;
    remove => collection.CollectionChanged -= value;
  }

  protected event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  event PropertyChangedEventHandler? INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
  {
    add => PropertyChanged += value;
    remove => PropertyChanged -= value;
  }

  public T this[int index] { get => collection[index]; set => collection[index] = value; }
  public int Count => collection.Count;
  public bool IsReadOnly => false;
  public bool Contains(T item) => collection.Contains(item);
  public int IndexOf(T item) => collection.IndexOf(item);
  public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) => collection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
  public void Add(T item) => collection.Add(item);
  public void Insert(int index, T item) => collection.Insert(index, item);
  public bool Remove(T item) => collection.Remove(item);
  public void RemoveAt(int index) => collection.RemoveAt(index);
  public void Clear() => collection.Clear();
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => collection.GetEnumerator();
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => collection.GetEnumerator();
}

ViewModel
internal class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private MyCollectionA<string> _collectionA = [];
  private MyCollectionB<string> _collectionB = [];

  public MyViewModel()
  {
    AddCommand = new MyCommand { Action = p => { CollectionA?.Add("A"); CollectionB?.Add("B"); } };
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  public MyCollectionA<string> CollectionA { get => _collectionA; set { _collectionA = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
  public MyCollectionB<string> CollectionB { get => _collectionB; set { _collectionB = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
  public ICommand AddCommand { get; }
  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  private sealed class MyCommand : ICommand
  {
    public MyCommand() { }
    public required Action<object?> Action { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => true;
    public void Execute(object? parameter) => Action?.Invoke(parameter);
  }
}

XAML
<Window 
  x:Class="WpfSandbox.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSandbox"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CollectionA.Count, StringFormat={}CollectionA.Count:{0}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CollectionB.Count, StringFormat={}CollectionB.Count:{0}}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Content="Add"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

環境

Windows 11
Visual Studio 2022
.NET 8

※ ソースを昔っぽく修正すれば、Visual Studio 2013、.NET Framework 4.5 でも再現できました。

原因がわかりました。
バインディングではイベントのobject senderの引数を参照して何かやっているみたいです。
そのためobject senderにはちゃんと自身のオブジェクトを渡さないといけなかったようです。
その根拠としてMyCollectionBの以下の行を
((INotifyPropertyChanged)collection).PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);

以下のように変更すると、MyCollectionBもCountの変更が反映されなくなりました。
((INotifyPropertyChanged)collection).PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(collection, args); // object sender に渡す内容を変更

イベントをダイレクトに橋渡しする場合は、object senderが自身のオブジェクトではないことに注意しないといけなかったということですね。
